# React - Handling Null values passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return a placeholder for the 'null' prop values.  I tried running a ternary operator and 'if' conditional statement to check if values exist before being rendered.

The props are passed from a parent component to a child component while data is being pushed to another child through react-router-dom's 'history' method.

When I run console.log the props are being passed properly however when I try to click on an image which contains 'null' I run into the current issue.

[image]

**Carousel.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import './Carousel.css';

const ImageCarousel = props => {
    const photos = props.history.location.state.resources.photos;
    return (
        <>
            <button className="backBtn" onClick={props.history.goBack}>Click to go back</button>
            <Carousel>
                {
                    photos.map(photo => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <img className='image' src={photo.url} alt="rental-carousel" />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </Carousel>
            <div className="address-container">
                <p className="address">Address:</p>
                <p className="address-info">{' '}{props.history && props.history.location.state.address}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ImageCarousel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if it's not null before getting `photos` value

```
const photos = props.history.location.state && props.history.location.state.resources ? 
    props.history.location.state.resources.photos : 
    [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new ? optional chaining operator:

```
const photos = props?.history?.location?.state?.resources?.photos;
```

and then check if photos is undefined before rendering

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

Check the null or undefined before assigning the prop

```
if (props === null ) {
 ......
}
const photos = props?.history?.location?.state?.resources?.photos;
```